# Mergesort not actually sorting

Tags: java, mergesort

I need to implement mergesort using only arrays for my parameter. I can see that it's splitting it up fine and reassembling it, but it's not actually sorting it while doing so. I'm sure it has to do with where/how I'm calling things. Can you help point out where it's not picking up the correct data so I can fix it?

```
public static void mergesort(Comparable[] a) {
    a = mergeSort(a);
}

public static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] a) {
    Comparable[] first, second;
    int length1 = a.length / 2;
    int length2 = a.length - length1;

    first = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, length1);
    second = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, length1, a.length);

    if(length1 > 0 && length2 > 0) {
        first = mergeSort(first);
        System.out.print("First: ");
        show(first);
        second = mergeSort(second);
        System.out.print("Second: ");
        show(second);
        a = merge(first, second);
        System.out.print("\nAfter: ");
        show(a);
    }
    return a;
}

public static Comparable[] merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] b) {
    Comparable[] temp = new Comparable[a.length + b.length];
    int aFirst = 0, aLast = a.length - 1;
    int bFirst = 0, bLast = b.length - 1;
    int index = aFirst;

    while(aFirst <= aLast && bFirst <= bLast) {
        if(a[aFirst].compareTo(b[bFirst]) < 0) {
            temp[index] = a[aFirst++];
        } else {
            temp[index] = b[bFirst++];
        }
        index++;
    }

    while(aFirst <= aLast) {
        temp[index] = a[aFirst++];
        index++;
    }

    while(bFirst <= bLast) {
            temp[index] = b[bFirst++];
            index++;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Edited to add: here's a snippet from the main method I'm working with (and which I cannot change).

```
    String[] b = {"S", "O", "R", "T", "E", "X", "A", "M", "P", "L", "E"};
    mergesort(b);
    assert isSorted(b);
    show(b);
```

Comment: Trust me, merge sort actually sorts.

Comment: I'm sure it does but this implementation is not actually sorting. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Since mergesort is void, you always throw the result away

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

These two calls:

```
mergesort(first);
mergesort(second);
```

sort the arrays `first` and `second` into new arrays, but you ignore those sorted arrays. Your code should be:

```
first = mergeSort(first);
second = mergesort(second);
```

---

The actual problem is, that you have two methods with similar names (`mergesort` and `mergeSort`) but very different intended behaviour: one of these methods tries to sort its input and return the sorted result without modifying the input, whereas the other does not return the sorted result and so has to modify its input.

Both approaches have there merits. But your current code mixes these to approaches, and that goes wrong.

---

What your current code is missing is storing the sorted elements back into argument array:

```
public static void mergesort(Comparable[] a) {
    Comparable[] sorted = mergeSort(a);
    System.arrayCopy(sorted, 0, a, 0, a.length);
}
```

And: if your helper methods are not to be called from outside your class make them `private` like this:

```
private static Comparable[] mergeSort(Comparable[] a) {
    ...
}

private static Comparable[] merge(Comparable[] a, Comparable[] b) {
    ...
}
```

and even rename the helper method into `mergeSortHelper`.

The ultimate goal is always to make your code as readable as possible and to show your intention to any reader of your code.

Comment: The second method mergeSort is suppose to be a helper method for recursion. That's probably what I'm doing incorrectly. I want to modify the input.